Can I use a named range cell value as a formula in Conditional Formatting
I have an Excel where, for user ease, I'd like to put the conditional formatting (CF) formulas in the spreadsheet itself, and give the cell a name.  Then use that single-cell range in the CF.
The affected range in the CF would be great too but if I put a range in the CF affected area field, it reverts back to cell-coordinates.
My overall goal is to replace all cell sticky coordinates with named ranges.  My users are not that savvy with Excel, neither am I honestly, but adoption of this thing I'm working will be greatly enhanced if users can work with words and not cell-references.
Thank you in advance.
I've attached two screenshots I think will explain it better.



This is not a Google Sheets question; the Sheets tag clearly says Do NOT use with [excel]. For some reason you keep re-adding the tag even after its edited out!

Im sorry.  I was in a hurry, and saw this tag on another similar question.   I'm a stupid freak.  If I can remove it, I will.

Cool... the tags are corrected now

Use INDIRECT:
=INDIRECT("Description_Error")

And correct there is no way to make the applies to refer to a named range or even a structured reference.  It will be converted to an actual range reference.

This is fabulous enough.  Thank you.  I need to learn more about INDIRECT(),

I got it to work... Yeah... Love this.

I spoke too soon.  I see how INDIRECT() works, thank you.  However, I also see cell-references in the conditional formatting formula treats cell references as absolutes and not relative.  I was seeing INDIRECT() affecting everything in 'Applies to'.   When I replace the INDIRECT("my formula") with the actual formula, it works.  Would using INDEX() or some other function work just as well but allow for relative cell references?
